# error while update sqlite table

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqlite

```
public void updateTable(String id, String name)
{   
    String strFilter = "realId=" + id;
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put("name", name);
    db.update("names", args, strFilter, null);
}
```

I get a null pointer exception on the below line :

```
db.update("names", args, strFilter, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you open the database? May be you haven't opened and could be the error.